# array elements cannot be modified c++

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

The knots elements in the array is not modified, the print out is always 0 for every elements, why is that?

```
double* knots;
knots = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * numKeys);
// Initializaiton
for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) {
    knots[i] = 0;
}
// assign value
for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) {
    knots[i] = -1 + i;
    printf("%d\n", knots[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using printf and malloc in `c++`. There are better alternatives in the `c++` standard library.

Comment: You can replace the initialization loop with [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

Comment: Rather than using dynamically allocated array (and having to delete the memory later), use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 3):

To print doubles use `"%lf\n"` instead. (lf = long float)

Comment: Note to users of old compilers: `%lf` requires C++11 or newer. `%f` can be used instead on older systems and is equivalent (for `printf`; not equivalent for `scanf`).

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`printf("%d\n", knots[i]);`

to this:

`printf("%f\n", knots[i]);`

Note: The `%f` reads double by default. In case you pass `float`, it will be converted to double first.